# Displaying Buffered percentage of Audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Why I am not able to display the buffered percentage of Audio using Javascript?

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("aone1");
var percentages = document.getElementById("aone1l");

function loop() {
  var buffered = audio.buffered;
  var loaded;
  var played;

  if (buffered.length) {
    loaded = 100 * buffered.end(0) / audio.duration;
    played = 100 * audio.currentTime / audio.duration;
    percentages[0].innerHTML = loaded.toFixed(2);
    percentages[1].innerHTML = played.toFixed(2);
  }

  setTimeout(loop, 50);
}

loop();
```

```html
<audio id="aone1" controls="controls">
   <source src="http://jainvidhya.epizy.com/Audio/Part1/ऑडियो नंबर 1 नमस्कार महामंत्र.mp4">
</audio>
<p>Loaded: <span id="aone1l"></span>%</p>
<p>Played: <span id="aone1l"></span>%</p>
```

Also why the audio takes much time to load?

Comment: `getElementById` will not give an array, it will give you an unique object element from DOM. use classes instead. **id's should be unique**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use unique `id` or use classes instead here, which will give you an array and then set the `innerHTML`:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("aone1");
var percentages = document.getElementsByClassName("aone1l")

function loop() {
  var buffered = audio.buffered;
  var loaded;
  var played;

  if (buffered.length) {
    loaded = 100 * buffered.end(0) / audio.duration;
    played = 100 * audio.currentTime / audio.duration;
    percentages[0].innerHTML = loaded.toFixed(2);
    percentages[1].innerHTML = played.toFixed(2);
  }

  setTimeout(loop, 50);
}

loop();
```

```html
<audio id="aone1" controls="controls">
   <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
</audio>
<p>Loaded: <span class="aone1l"></span>%</p>
<p>Played: <span class="aone1l"></span>%</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. If I change `var audio` to `var audio1o` so is there any more replacements with the same?

Comment: I did not change the variable name, though you can change it if you want. I just used classes instead of id's.

Comment: Can you please change the variable. (replace `audio` to any)

Comment: Not that, change this text: `var audio` to `var (any)`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the variable name, you might be thinking to use multiple audio's in a same page, in that case as well use the class names and use an array.